# Managing Views inside ViewFlipper?

Tags: android

This might be a really stupid question, but I can't find any information regarding this.

I have 4 Layouts inside a view flipper, and I switch between them manually, using the setDisplayedChild. This is working perfectly, and exactly what I need.

My question is, is there a built-in way of managing which is the next & previous views? I could use the built-in methods of the ViewFlipper, to move to the next/previous child. However there will be the case when I want to move from child 1, directly to child 4.

I have some code in place, which manages it quite well, just curious if the SDK has something built in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, is there a built-in way of managing which is the next & previous views?

Change the order of the children via `addView()`, `removeView()`, `bringChildToFront()`, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Knew there had to of been a simpler way.